# qt moc header in different packages

Tags: qt, cmake, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a typical project is set in CMakeLists.txt

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

if i create a lib and have headers in the include folders that depending packages require....

Now I have an rqt package, where I want to use a custom widget I create in this package in several sub packages. Is there any way to do that? Because now I cannot just add the include folder to INCLUDE_DIRS because the headers lying there might need to be moc'ed... I cannot directly compile against them...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190328/qt-moc-header-in-different-packages/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I've seen, the existing C++ libraries in ROS that expose QT widgets don't do anything special to expose the MOC'd files that are generated from headers.

Between reading the [qt_gui_cpp CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/blob/groovy-devel/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp/CMakeLists.txt) and some [MOC documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) it looks like MOC creates C++ implementation files only (My interpretation of the documentation is that MOC does not generate header files). These generated C++ files are then compiled into a library within the source project. Downstream projects then include the original headers and link against the compiled library.

In your case, you'd want to make sure that the `${PROJECT_NAME}` library contains both your source and the MOC-generated files.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-08-18**:
Thank you very much, exposing widgets works as you suggested.... Addition: Some pkgs expose ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} in catkin_package INCLUDE_DIRS; This might be necessary, however, I could not test if necessary because both of my packages add it to include_directories anyway...